# Backbone.js views delegateEvents do not get bound (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm using Backbone.js and sometimes the [views events](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents) do not get bound correctly.

I can check the event binding situation with `$(viewselector).data()` in jQuery. Most of the time there are events, sometimes there aren't!

Are there any known things I should watch out for that can cause this?

Comment: Can you please post more details and possibly some code as well? Also, what is your javascript load order? You need to make sure that jQuery/Zepto is loaded before underscore and backbone.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for your help, jQuery is loaded before us/backbone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Events are delegated to this.el when the view is initialized. So you need to:

- Create the view by giving the constructor the "el" option to specify the element
- Define el, tag, id, classname on your view to create or find on the page your element directly.
- Append your rendered view to the "el" element of the view
- Make sure you do not replace the "el" element after the view creation

For the last item, if you have to do it, you can call delegateEvents once more to re-delegate the event on your view.

Comment: The `events: {}` block in Backbone.js uses jQuery's .delegate() function, which is just a special form of the .live() function, which is itself a special form of the .bind() function that can be declared before a DOM element exists. It shouldn't be necessary to define the "el" attribute to get the elements to work, since backbone.js will either user tagName or give you a div by default.

Comment: Right, the auto generated div is there and not overwritten, it's what I'm looking at to check whether or not it has the event bound. When it does have an event object, it shows me in firebug the events bound to the el. I presume these can be bubbled to from child elements. But sometimes the event object doesn't exist after loading. Firebug doesn't even show any errors. How do I call delegateEvents? Is it just this.delegateEvents ? or something else.

Comment: @Andrew what is was explaining is that you should not re-assign this.el because you will then loose that delegation magic. So in the case where you already have an element on the page, you must pass it aqs an option to the view to have the delegation working.

Comment: @friisource yes this.delegateEvents(). The other thing you can check is pretty obvious:are the selectors selecting anything  once your view is rendered. Also the delegation works by adding events to the base element ( live works with events on body for example) and relies on the propagation of events. So if you el.delegate('click', 'button') the event will be bound to el and when the event bubble up to this element jquery will check for a match of 'button' on the target element.

Comment: @Julien ahhh... good point. However, when would you want to reassign the element of a view? I can't think of a case when you'd want to do that.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, i had to assign live events outside the .el element and was wondering why it wasn't working!

Comment: Just needed to call `delegateEvents` again because I'd replaced the el.  Boom, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

My approach in these scenarios is to add `delegateEvents()` in render of each view that has an event, like the following:

```
  $(this.el).empty();
  $(this.el).html(this.template({}));
  this.delegateEvents(); // this will bind all events ONCE AGAIN
```

This is perfect for views specially created dynamically i.e. views that are declared new under each click or so...

Comment: eek...take care you are not leaking event bindings. i think this will happen if you are repeatedly binding (delegateEvents-ing) but not unbinding previous bindings.

Comment: @aaron `html` calls `empty` ["which unbinds all jQuery events on all child nodes"](http://ianstormtaylor.com/rendering-views-in-backbonejs-isnt-always-simple/). You need to call `delegateEvents` in this situation every time, or use `setElement` (see the article).

Comment: also, `delegateEvents` calls `undelegateEvents` before delegating the `events` hash.

Comment: using `view.remove()` will call `Events.stopListening`