# How to bind change event in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to load country list and on select the country i just want to call an alert , but somehow I am not able to catch change event for the select box.

Can somebody please help me?

here is the code with the view, model and collection part with template script in html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Backbone</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/template" id="country_select_template">
        <select id="country-selector">
             <% _.each(countries, function(country) {%>
                <option value="<%= country.fipsCode %>"><%= country.countryName %></option>
            <% }); %>
        </select>
    </script>
    <div id="country_select_container">
        Loading country...
    </div>

    <!--div>
    <select id="state" disabled=true>
        <option value="NAN">Select State</option>                    
    </select>
    </div>
    <div>
    <select id="city" disabled=true>
        <option value="NAN">Select City</option>                    
    </select>
    </div-->
</div>
<ul id="names-list">
</ul>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script>

Country = Backbone.Model.extend();

CountryList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Country,
    url : "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18190667/countryList.json",
    parse : function(response) {
        return response.geonames;
    }
});

Countries = new CountryList();

CountryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "change #country-selector": "countrySelected"
    },

    countrySelected: function(){
        alert("You can procceed!!!");
    },

    countrySelected  :function(){
        alert("Procceed");
    },

    initialize: function(){
        var countries = [];
        var self = this;
        Countries.fetch({
            success: function(){
                self.render();
            }
        });
    },

    render: function(){
        var self = this;
        var country_select_template = _.template($("#country_select_template").html(), {
            countries: Countries.toJSON(),
        });
        $('#country_select_container').html(country_select_template);
        return this;
    }
});
var view = new CountryView();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try like this:

```
CountryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#country_select_container"),
    template: _.template($("#country_select_template").html()),
    events: {
        "change #country-selector": "countrySelected"
    },

    countrySelected: function(){
        alert("You can procceed!!!");
    },

    initialize: function(){
        var self = this;
        Countries.fetch({
            success: function(){
                self.render();
            }
        });
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(
           this.template({countries: Countries.toJSON()})
        );
        return this;
    }
});
```

For more info check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125958/backbone-js-views-delegateevents-do-not-get-bound-sometimes), and hopefully this will be helpful :)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'html' of undefined @this.$el.html statement? any idea?

but $(this.el).html(...) worked for me

Comment: @Urvish: I guess you're using an old version of backbone.js, the new version 0.9 have a ``this.$el`` shortcut for ``$(this.el)``. Check here (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#upgrading)

Comment: `el` is supposed to be a DOM object not a jQuery one.

`el: document.getElementById('country_select_container')` or `el: $('#country_select_container').get(0)`

Comment: Your answer is not good, you shoul had put in the alert the newly selected value."

Answer (score 0):

You must bind the view to an existing DOM element. Try this:

```
CountryView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el:'#country-selector',

    events: {
        "change #country-selector": "countrySelected"
    },

...
```

Or in your case you can pass the `el` parameter as an argument to the constructor:

`new CountryView({el:'#country-selector'});`

If you don't bind `el` to an existing DOM element, backbone will bind it to a div by default. Thus your events will be fired looking for `div > #country-selector` and won't match since no such element exists.

Comment: i tried new CountryView({el:'#country-selector'}); but still not able to alert? any other suggestion?