# Backbone: Navigate function not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router

So for some reason navigate won't work in one of my views. I'm doing everything in one file for now, so that may be the problem. Also I know the code is horrible, I'm just messing around with backbone right now.

EDIT: I put a `console.log()` in MarketingPage's function `route` and it never gets called, so there must be something wrong with the view.

Also, this is the error I'm getting from chrome dev tools:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1 Error: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.
    at P (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:16:142)
    at null.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:18:417)
    at chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:1:182
    at miscellaneous_bindings:288:9
    at chrome.Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:390:21)
    at chrome.Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:376:27)
    at chrome.Event.dispatch (event_bindings:396:17)
    at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage (miscellaneous_bindings:254:22)
```

Here's my code:

```
/*global public, $*/


window.public = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Routers: {

    },
    init: function () {
        console.log('Hello from Backbone!');
    }
};

var App = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        'register': 'route_register',
    },

    index: function(){
        var marketing_page = new MarketingPage();
    },

    route_register: function(){
        var register_view = new RegisterView();
    }
});

window.app = new App();

var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/user',
    defaults: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }
});

var MarketingPage = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
    this.render();
  },
  render: function(){
    var template = _.template($("#marketing-page").html());
        $('.search-box').after(template);
  },
  events: {
    'dblclick': 'route'
  },
  route: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("In route");
      window.app.navigate('register', {trigger: true});
      this.remove();
  }
});

var RegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        var template = _.template($("#register-template").html());
        $('.search-box').after(template);
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

When I type `host/#register` into the browser directly, the register view gets rendered, but no matter what I do the click event won't seem to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the handler function `route` isn't being called, it's likely that the event delegation isn't working.

One thing to note is that the event handling that is set up in a Backbone View is scoped to only that view's `el`. I don't see where yours is set up explicitly, so it might be creating an empty div, then handling events inside that empty div (which you don't want).

One trick I use for quick prototypes is to set the view's `el` with a jQuery selector pointing to something that exists on the page already, then in the `render`, show it with a `.show()`.

Since you're not really doing that, here's one thing you could try. What we're doing is setting the `$el` content and then calling `delegateEvents` to make sure that the events and handlers are being bound.

```
var MarketingPage = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.render();
  },
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html(_.template($("#marketing-page").html()));
    $('.search-box').after(this.$el);
    this.delegateEvents();
  },
  events: {
    'dblclick': 'route'
  },
  route: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("In route");
      window.app.navigate('register', {trigger: true});
      this.remove();
  }
});
```

[Backbone.js views delegateEvents do not get bound (sometimes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125958/backbone-js-views-delegateevents-do-not-get-bound-sometimes)

http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents

Comment: Yeah route never gets called.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I would implement delegateEvents()

Comment: Is the `#marketing-page` and `#register-template` already in the page and visible?